# ¿Cómo puedo extraer una subcadena de una cadena en NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, regex

Tengo una regex el cual es `GPS:[A-Z];[\d]+;[NS]+[\d.]+;[WE]+[\d.]+` y necesito sacarlo de un cadena tipo

`*GS06,357041069025628,202244150119,,SYS:SP4603NS;V2.31;V1.1.8,GPS:A;11;N6.041257;W75.412512,COT:730620,ADC:11.29;4.00,DTT:0;E0;;;0;1#`

Por ejemplo en Python yo puedo usar la opción `findall()` de la librería re, quisiera saber si en Node tengo una opción parecida o como puedo hacerla.

Ejemplo en python

```
import re

message = "*GS06,357041069025628,202244150119,,SYS:SP4603NS;V2.31;V1.1.8,GPS:A;11;N6.041257;W75.412512,COT:730620,ADC:11.29;4.00,DTT:0;E0;;;0;1#"

nwgps = re.findall(r'GPS:[A-Z];[\d]+;[NS]+[\d.]+;[WE]+[\d.]+', message)

print(nwgps)
```

Output:

```
GPS:A;11;N6.041257;W75.412512
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Hola pues son expresiones regulares solamente. Y node JS es javascript.

```js
    let string = "*GS06,357041069025628,202244150119,,SYS:SP4603NS;V2.31;V1.1.8,GPS:A;11;N6.041257;W75.412512,COT:730620,ADC:11.29;4.00,DTT:0;E0;;;0;1#" //Mi cadena
    let re = new RegExp(/GPS:[A-Z];[\d]+;[NS]+[\d.]+;[WE]+[\d.]+/);//expresion regular del algoritmo original
    let findAll = string.match(re)//buscamos las coincidencias con match
    console.log(findAll[0]) //imprimimos la primer coincidencia
    console.log(findAll) //o todas si es que la shay
```